# How exactly do potions and oils work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

So I read the bit about potions in the CRB and it sayss a potion can have the effect of a spell up to 3rd level.

It says with potions that the drinker is the target and the caster.  So if I drink a *Remove Disease* potion, do I roll a d20 + MY level or the original caster's level?

What about offensive spells like *Magic Missle*?  Can they be potions and oils?  How would that work?

Comment: Magic items use the caster level it was crafted, normally the minimum required to cast that spell. Pretty sure staffs allow you to use your own CL if it's higher but that's the exception.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The caster level of the spell is set when the potion is created**

This is covered under the [Brew Potion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/brew-potion-item-creation---final) feat. When the rules state that you are both the caster and target of the spell, this is for purposes of spells that refer to the caster in their effect.

Typically, potions generated by random treasure tables will have the minimum caster level for the spell. So remove disease potions will typically be caster level 5.

**You CAN create potions from offensive spells, but they're not super effective**

There's no restriction preventing you from brewing a potion of Magic Missile (it's a spell of 3rd level or lower, which targets a creature or object). But remember that you are both the caster and the *target* of the spell once you consume the potion... In other words, anyone who drinks the potion will take 1d4 + 1 points of force damage.

**Addenda**

[Eric B](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/8254/eric-b) notes that the [magic item creation rules for potions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Potions) forbid you from creating potions of spells that have a range of personal.

[Hey I Can Chan](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/8610/hey-i-can-chan) notes that the Brew Potion feat does not allow you to create oils (although allowing Brew Potion to do so is not an unreasonable house rule).

Comment: Interesting, can the craft skill allow you to create Oils if say your craft is Alchemy?

Comment: @Nerevar Nope; that is, not if the oil creates a spell effect. It *is* a perfectly valid house rule that they can be created by the feat Brew Potion, though.